# I am trying to write a VBA routine to open a csv file copy and paste values into another workbook but seem to keep falling over

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to write a VBA routine to open a `csv` file  copy and paste values into another workbook but seem to keep falling over

```
Sub GetWorkFlowMaxData()

 Dim DataSheet As Object
 Dim InpDataBook As Object
 Dim InpDataSheet As Object
 Dim WorkFlowMaxFileName As String
 Dim vResponse As Variant
 Dim sCurrSheet As String
 Dim main As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sCurrSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

ActiveSheet.Calculate




vResponse = MsgBox("This action can not be undone. Are you sure you want to clear Historic WorkFlowMax Data ?", vbYesNo, "Clear Data")

If vResponse = vbYes Then

main = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Workbooks(main).Sheets("WFM_Detail").Range("A1:G10000").ClearContents




        WorkFlowMaxFileName = Range("WorkFlowMaxFile")



            Workbooks.Open Filename:=WorkFlowMaxFileName

            Set InpDataBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set InpDataSheet = ActiveSheet
            InpDataBook.Activate

'            other = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'            Workbooks(InpDataBook).Sheets("InpDataSheet").Range("A1:G10000").Copy


'            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
       End If


' Application.Calculate
 End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see where you are passing the path and filename of the "WorkFlowMaxFile" document, being my first guess. Otherwise, could you share the errors you are receiving?

Comment: is a named range in a front Control Worksheet in the weorkbook

Comment: i want the routine to open that file (saved CSV file output) which it does and then copy and paste special values only into the same sheet that has the names range in at as above ..then shut the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you set the workbook and Sheet variables correctly in the code you can directly use them like below...

```
InpDataSheet.Range("A1:G10000").Copy
```

Modify the following code as per your requirement...

```
Sub GetWorkFlowMaxData()
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim WorkFlowMaxFileName As String
    Dim vResponse As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    vResponse = MsgBox("This action can not be undone. Are you sure you want to clear Historic WorkFlowMax Data ?", vbYesNo, "Clear Data?")

    If vResponse = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("WFM_Detail")

    WorkFlowMaxFileName = Range("WorkFlowMaxFile").Value

    wsDest.Range("A1").ClearContents

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=WorkFlowMaxFileName
    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = ActiveSheet

    wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy wsDest.Range("A1")

    wbSource.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = ture
End Sub
```

Comment: ta i will give that a crack txvm

Comment: so we have 2 sheets here: the active workbook which has all sorts of sheets in it and one is called WFM_detail ....the CopyFromPath file is easy that would be the path specified as a named range in my front sheet...also CopyToPath..what about the CopyFromSheet and the copyFromRange..how will they work...eg the CSV output file i wish to copy eg for ydays data is called this but will change daily ...20170405-Time Report_All__Consu...and the CopyToSheet will be a sheet called "WFM_Detail" in the original sheet...the ranges will be InpDataSheet.Range("A1:G10000").Copy etc

Comment: I have added the code in my solution, modify it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are asking after you set the provided variables to the appropriate values.

```
Sub GetWorkFlowMaxData()
    Dim copyFrom, copyTo As Workbook
    Dim copyFromPath, copyToPath As String
    Dim copyFromSheet, copyToSheet As String
    Dim copyFromRange, copyToRange As Range

    Set copyFrom = Workbooks.Open(copyFromPath)
    Set copyTo = Workbooks.Open(copyToPath)

    copyFrom.Sheets(copyFromSheet).Range(copyFromRange).Copy
    copyTo.Sheets(copyToSheet).Range(copyToRange).PasteSpecial
    copyFrom.Close
End Sub
```